# In Mediawiki, where are my changes actually stored

Tags: mediawiki

When I actually write in the wiki, where are the changes actually being stored?

I have searched the source code for keywords that i have actually written and i cant find it, which obviously means its being stored where it cannot be searched directly.

I have made changes to it i.e. written in it, but sourcetree does not seem to be recognising it.

Comment: This .. really doesn't seem to be a programming question, in fact it's rather hard to understand what you're asking. Are you after the DB table? If you can edit your question for clarity so that it's clearly on topic and answerable, please flag it for moderator review.

Comment: Yeh I get this alot on StackExchange/overflow, that they dont know what I am talking about, yet they are expects apparantly. You lot want me to write an essay. If you dont know what Im talking about, why answer?? furthermore why do you answer with a question or even a series of questions?? as if thats going to help me?                                        If this isny t programming question i dont know what is

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the site's contents? They are stored in a database file which is read and written by the code.

It would be quite unmaintainable, if not outright dangerous, to mix user-submitted data with executable code.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in a database table called page (or  something similar)